# How to insert a block inside the content?

Tags: views, blocks

I need to insert a block inside in a specific place of my Drupal posts of only one type.

I understand that would be done through `page.tpl.php` file but can somebody explain how do I actually create that block in the first place and ascribe the right name to it? I tried searching in documentation and I'm a bit confused... Thank you!

```
    <div id="content-wrap">
                <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
                    <?php if ($title): ?>
                      <h1 class="page-title"><?php print $title;  ?></h1>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

                <!-- I GUESS THE NEW BLOCK GOES IN HERE BUT WHERE DO I SET IT UP? -->

                <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You render the block in the preprocess function for that template. Each template (with its family of suggestions) has a preprocess function. For instance, if you are rendering page.tpl.php or a suggestion based off that, then the preprocess will be named THEME_preprocess_page ([template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) in the docs).

Inside the preprocess function you add a new key to the $vars array, and set it to the html output that you want printed. Then, in the template file (ie page.tpl.php) you print that variable.

**example:**

**template.php file**

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
  $vars['my_block'] = render($block['content']);
}
```

**page.tpl file:**

```
<?php print $my_block; ?>
```

You can also just assign the block to a region (below content for instance) and then move it out of there into wherever you want it by using [hook_page_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7).

[Drupal 7 preprocess tutorial adding variable to template](http://purencool.com/drupal-7-preprocess-tutorial-adding-variable-to-template)

[Using hook_page_alter to move node render items into blocks](http://drupal.aspcode.net/ppst/63547274810018958055238/using-hookpagealter-to-move-node-render-items-into-blocks)

[Placing the contents of a block in any location](https://www.drupal.org/node/26502)

[Drupal 7 - How to Print Blocks in templates](http://www.wdtutorials.com/2012/04/16/drupal-7-how-print-blocks-templates#.VMfMCWiUfjU)

Comment: You can also use the `hook_preprocess_page` in a custom module to decouple it from your theme. And to create the block see [this](http://kahthong.com/2013/06/create-your-own-custom-drupal-block-programmatically)